# Let $\:P: R^2 \to R$. To be more precise, $P(x,y)=x$. Is there a closed set A in $R^2$ s.t. P(A) is not a closed set in $R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

At first, I want to map isolated dots in $R^2$  to $R$ in order to create a open sphere, but I find it useless as the cardinal number of a open sphere and that of the isolated dots are not equal.

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 6):

Take $A=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,\middle|\,x>0\wedge y=\frac1x\right\}$. It is closed, but $P(A)=(0,\infty)$.

Comment: We need a you'd-better-type-fast tag...